# Unable to export Azure SQL database to storage with firewall

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

When running the command `az sql db export`
I get error:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException ... 404 Forbidden
```

Because it is unable to connect to the Storage Account. It works when I **allow all networks** in the Firewall.

This can't be right, is there another way to allow the SqlServer to connect to the storage account?

Note: "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account" did nothing. Both are in the same Locations.

Comment: Please note that Azure SQL Database is not in the list of "Trusted Microsoft Services" - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security#exceptions.

Comment: Hi Yannick, does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you only set "Allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account", we still can not access the Storage.

I tested on Portal and will get bellow error:
[image]

But you could add you client IP to the Storage firewall settings, it can solve the problem:
[image]

This sound like Azure SQL database firewall settings, once add you client IP to the firewall, you can access the Storage account now.

Hope this helps.